# Passing jQuery object through History.pushState() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser-history, pushstate

I'm using History.pushState() function, I'm saving into push state object an jQuery object, but when statechange event is fired I'm retriving state object data without jQuery object, but only "normal" object:

```
var object = {link : $("#varianty")};

console.log(object.link);   

History.pushState(object,"test","test.php");
```

### Console returns jQuery object

`jQuery(div#varianty.box)`

### But when the statechange event is fired:

```
History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){       

        var State = History.getState();

        var link = State.data.link;

        console.log(link);     
});
```

### Console return an object

`Object { length=1, 0={...}, more...}`

### Detailed dump

```
0 =>    Object { jQuery1304643255828=39, constructor={...}}

context =>  Object { location={...}}

length =>   1

selector  =>    "#varianty"
```

Is there any chance to retrive in state object jQuery object, if no, there is not cool way but I can again select the object by:
`$(State.data.link.selector);`

But then is useless to pass jQuery object through pushState object...

Need it to push `$(this)` object on click event.

Thanks for any advice or solution! :)

Comment: A little confused: your first code block doesn't select a jQuery object at all, and according to the detailed dump (if that is of the retrieved object) then it is a jQuery object...so I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: I've deleted '$' by mistake, when I was formating the text.

Answer (score 2):

Objects that you pass to the pushState function seem to loose their prototype when yielded in the popstate event.  To get around this you can re-attach the prototype when listening to the event.

In your case though it might be better to pass just the selector for the element you need into pushState

```
history.pushState({selector: "#my-div"}, "test", "/test")
```

That way you can just grab the element from the dom on the popstate event with jQuery

```
history.onpopstate = function (event) {
  if (event.state) {
    var myElem = $(event.state.selector)
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank's for your suggestion!. But I need the object, becouse when the code is advance like this: $('.links').click(function(e){ var object = {item: $(this)};history.pushState(object,"test","test");e.preventDefault();});